# How to prevent Django fixtures from conflicting with existing data

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do `manage.py loaddata myfixture.json` to purposely bulk overwrite several records in my database. However, it gives me the error:

```
IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture 'myfixture.json': Could not load myapp.Person(pk=1): (1062, "Duplicate entry 'Bob' for key 'name'")
```

I thought the behavior of loaddata was to overwrite the records if primary key matches an existing record? Am I wrong, or was this changed in Django 1.5? How do I get it to overwrite?

Comment: are you sure primary key matches? can you post part for Bob from myfixture.json? are you sure Bob in db has pk=1 ?

Comment: Did you try to create your fixture with natural keys (dumpdata --natural)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to modify Django's loaddata command to properly parse natural keys while loading, and avoid re-loading duplicates. The modified command is published [here](https://gitlab.com/chrisspen/django-admin-steroids/blob/master/admin_steroids/management/commands/loaddatanaturally.py). The only differences between the official loaddata are lines 189-201.

Comment: Your link gives a 404 :-/

Comment: @ArnoDeceuninck Updated. It should be noted this answer is now very old and I believe the standard loaddata command may have this feature built into it.